Is there @property like behavior outside of a class in Python3?
I am reading and writing values in a two-dimensional array. I find it kind of verbose to say grid[row][column] every time I read and write from a cell, especially because I like to deal with one variable cell = (i,j) to keep track of cells rather than with two variables row, column = i, j. I would like to do something like the following:
def value(cell):
    row, column = cell
    return grid[row][column]
value(cell) += 5

And have the actual cell in the grid update.
I believe that the functionality is possible in classes using the property, but I would like to find a way to do this without having to create a class around it. Is there any way to do that?
Here is the full code that I'm working with right now:
from typing import List
from itertools import product


class Solution:
    def minPathSum(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        m, n = len(grid), len(grid[0])

        def cell_above(cell):
            row, column = cell
            return (row-1, column)

        def cell_to_the_left(cell):
            row, column = cell
            return (row, column-1)

        def value(cell):
            row, column = cell
            return grid[row][column]

        def add_value(cell, val):
            row, column = cell
            grid[row][column] += val

        first_row = ((0, i) for i in range(1, n))
        first_column = ((j, 0) for j in range(1, m))
        cells = product(range(1, m), range(1, n))
        last_cell = (m-1, n-1)

        for cell in first_row:
            add_value(cell, value(cell_to_the_left(cell)))
        for cell in first_column:
            add_value(cell, value(cell_above(cell)))
        for cell in cells:
            add_value(cell, min(value(cell_above(cell)), value(cell_to_the_left(cell))))
        return value(last_cell)

I would like the bottom part of this code to look more like this:
for cell in first_row:
    value(cell) += value(cell_to_the_left(cell))
for cell in first_column:
    value(cell) += value(cell_above(cell))
for cell in cells:
    value(cell) += min(value(cell_above(cell)), value(cell_to_the_left(cell)))

I tried the following:
def value_setter(cell):
    row, column = cell
    def set_value(val):
        grid[row][column] = val
    return set_value

def value(cell):
    row, column = cell
    return property(lambda : grid[row][column], value_setter(cell))

for cell in first_row:
    val = value(cell)
    val += value(cell_to_the_left(cell))

I got the following error from this code:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'property' and 'property'
val += value(cell_to_the_left(cell))
Line 34 in minPathSum (Solution.py)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ret = Solution().minPathSum(param_1)
Line 59 in _driver (Solution.py)
_driver()
Line 70 in <module> (Solution.py)

Is there any way to make this work with the builtin property function, or any other functionality that mimics the behavior that I am looking for?

It looks like you just want cell to be a tuple. You can assign a tuple with cell = (i, j) and you can later unpack it with i, j = cell. No complications with classes or properties required. Note that I think cell isn't a great name for a coordinate. After all, the variable called cell doesn't refer to a cell, it refers to a coordinate of a cell.

You can just create a super-small class and write __getitem__ and __setitem__  methods for it. Otherwise, just use a dictionary with the coordinates as keys, instead of a list of lists:  ( annotated like: dict[tuple[int, int], int] , declared just as dict() )  for your grid.

There’s no way to assign to a function call expression, class or not. You can assign to a slicing expression, though, like value[cell], which will call* value’s __getitem__ and __setitem__:
class GridWrapper:
    """
    Converts 2D tuple item access to nested item access.
    """
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid

    def __getitem__(self, coord):
        row, column = coord
        return self.grid[row][column]

    def __setitem__(self, coord, value):
        row, column = coord
        self.grid[row][column] = value


value = GridWrapper(grid)

* Actually, will prefer to call the value’s __iadd__ when you use +=, but this is the correct behavior in any case
